# Providing a connection pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, comparative-review, connection-pool

I need some opinions about method naming and single responsibility principle.

First of all, let's talk about method naming. The class below was created to provide a connection pool and whenever a pool is needed the `get_pool` is called. In the end `get_pool` will return a pool but the method will do more than only one responsibility, which is creating a pool if one doesn't exist and returning a pool. Besides, `get_pool name` is a very usual and comfortable name. Shouldn't something related to pool creation be mentioned in the method name, like `get_pool_or_create_if_not_exists()`?

I understand that "get" methods should only do "read" operations but if you will do more than these then it should be mentioned in the method name, isn't it?

```
class DBPoolNameEnum(Enum):
    DESIGN = "db"
    CENTRAL = "db_central"


class AsyncDatabasePoolManager:
    connection_pools = {}
    lock = asyncio.Lock()

    @staticmethod
    async def get_pool(db_pool_name_enum: DBPoolNameEnum):
        db_config = config[db_pool_name_enum.value]
        pool_name = db_pool_name_enum.value

        if pool_name not in AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools:
            async with AsyncDatabasePoolManager.lock:
                if pool_name not in AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools:
                    AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools[pool_name] = await aiomysql.create_pool(
                        maxsize=100,
                        autocommit=True,
                        pool_recycle=2 * 60 * 60,
                        connect_timeout=2 * 60,
                        conv=AsyncDatabasePoolManager._get_conversions(),
                        user=db_config["user"],
                        password=db_config["password"],
                        host=db_config["host"],
                        db=db_config["database"])

        return AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools[pool_name]

    @staticmethod
    async def shutdown():
        for pool in AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools.values():
            pool.close()
            await pool.wait_closed()

    @classmethod
    def _get_conversions(cls):
        conversions[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = ord
        return conversions
```

Continue the discussion, there is another implementation of this class (see below) which splits `get_pool` into two methods, one to create a pool and assign to a dict and another to get a pool from a dict.

The way to use it is, in the beginning of the program, create a pool should be called and whenever a pool is needed `get_pool` should be called. If `get_pool` is called before `create_pool`, then an exception will be raised because a pool was never created.

These approach intent to separate concerns and keep methods names concise.

1. Does it make sense?
2. What approach is better? Please consider which approach will be better understood for a future programmer, best practices of class design, best practice of naming conventions, etc.

````
class AsyncDatabasePoolManager:
    connection_pools = {}
    lock = asyncio.Lock()

    @staticmethod
    async def create_pool(pool_name, user, password, host, database):
        if pool_name not in AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools:
            async with AsyncDatabasePoolManager.lock:
                if pool_name not in AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools:
                    AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools[pool_name] = await aiomysql.create_pool(
                        maxsize=100,
                        autocommit=True,
                        pool_recycle=2 * 60 * 60,
                        connect_timeout=2 * 60,
                        # read_timeout=3*60,
                        # write_timeout=3*60,
                        conv=AsyncDatabasePoolManager._get_conversions(),
                        user=user,
                        password=password,
                        host=host,
                        db=database)

    @staticmethod
    def get_pool(pool_name):
        return AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools[pool_name]

    @staticmethod
    async def shutdown():
        for pool in AsyncDatabasePoolManager.connection_pools.values():
            pool.close()
            await pool.wait_closed()

    @classmethod
    def _get_conversions(cls):
        conversions[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = ord
        return conversions
```
````